# What is a CPU scheduler?

Tags: operating-system, definition

After I read all the CPU scheduling algorithms I found that I don't understand the phrase *a CPU Scheduler*, whose job is to pick the next process to get the CPU, in my book. Is it a module or an abstract concept about the scheduling algorithms itself?

(Sorry I cannot provide the name of the book since it's not written in english, but it also says: *After the scheduler is triggered the dispatcher will get executed*, not sure whether this would help.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a computer concept and not directly related to programming, it may be better asked on [Computer Science.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that, it's not an uninteresting question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is meant by CPU Scheduler are threads. With threads, processes are being regulated and controlled. Once a process has a CPU, it will lock it until the process is closed or a certain time. Threads are really useful because they allow executing tasks at almost the same time.

I hope this helps a bit, if you need more information, leave a comment and I can write some more.

Cheerio :)

Comment: I have edit my q to provide more context, if you would like to know.

Comment: I found you're right that it should be a thread from the answer [Relationship between IO scheduler and cpu/process scheduler?@Linux/Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/199265/324192)

Comment: Sorry sir, would you mind my request that you delete both of you answer? I want to delete my question because people here don't like my question. But I will remember your kindness.